# TypeError: context must be a dict rather than Context

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a search engine into a django blog application and when I ran the command:

```
>>> manage.py build_solr_schema
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KOLAPO\Google Drive\Python\Websites\mysite\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\KOLAPO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\KOLAPO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\KOLAPO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\KOLAPO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\KOLAPO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\haystack\management\commands\build_solr_schema.py", line 29, in handle
    schema_xml = self.build_template(using=using)
  File "C:\Users\KOLAPO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\haystack\management\commands\build_solr_schema.py", line 57, in build_template
    return t.render(c)
  File "C:\Users\KOLAPO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 64, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "C:\Users\KOLAPO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 287, in make_context
    raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than Context.
```

What's wrong?

Note: I'm using Solr and Django-haystack for the search engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue has been fixed by [pull request 1504](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/pull/1504/commits/295584314e19a191a59450e053b21809adceca2a), but it looks like there hasn't been a release since then.

Comment: This is correct.  That's my PR!  He cut an alpha release you can grab with pip (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-haystack/2.7.dev0).  You can also grab directly from github with a syntax like  `pip install git+https://github.com/RabidCicada/django-haystack@BRANCHNAME/COMMIT#egg=django-haystack`